# corrupted CreateSliceOptions types @reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Using `reducers` in my slice instance ( redux/toolkit ) I get this error.
`'reducers' does not exist in type 'CreateSliceOptions<unknown, SliceCaseReducers<unknown>, string>'.ts(2345)`
Instead of reducers, addPermissions exits in type (CreateSliceOptions).
I guess something might have gone wrong with my typescript types

code:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface IPermission {}

interface IState {
    userPermissions: IPermission[];
}

export const initialState: IState = {
    userPermissions: localStorage.getItem("token") ? [] : [],
};

export const permissionSlice = createSlice({
    name: "permissions",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addPermission: (state: any, action: any) => {
            state.userPermissions = action.payload;
        },
    },
});

export const { addPermission } = permissionSlice.actions;
export default permissionSlice.reducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by corrupted redux node_modules. I removed all redux node_modules and reinstalled them, which fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Redux maintainer.

**Most likely the *real* problem is the use of `(state: any, action: any)` in your `addPermissions` reducer.  *Don't do this!***.

The right answer is to *not* provide any type for `state`, because it will be automatically inferred from the `initialState` field, and then use RTK's `PayloadAction` to type the `action` parameter:

```
export const permissionSlice = createSlice({
    name: "permissions",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addPermission: (state, action: PayloadAction<IPermission[]>) => {
            state.userPermissions = action.payload;
        },
    },
});
```

Please make sure you're following the approach we show in our Redux docs TS setup page:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/typescript-quick-start

Comment: I'm still getting the same err: `Argument of type '{ name: string; initialState: IState; reducers: { addPermission: (state: any, action: PayloadAction<IPermission[]>) => void; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CreateSliceOptions<unknown, SliceCaseReducers<unknown>, string>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'reducers' does not exist in type 'CreateSliceOptions<unknown, SliceCaseReducers<unknown>, string>'.ts(2345)`

Comment: Looks like there is something wrong with the `CreateSliceOptions` there is no reducers in it and instead there is `addPermissions` as a required property.

Comment: Something seems very wrong with your project, then. Can you post a CodeSandbox or a Github repo that shows this error happening?  I still think that it sounds like you're using `state: any`, and you **should_ not_ use `: any` in there!**

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. The problem was with the node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the type of the slice state is IState, so you should update the type of the reducers field to be SliceCaseReducers.

```
import { createSlice, SliceCaseReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

interface IPermission {}

interface IState {
    userPermissions: IPermission[];
}

export const initialState: IState = {
    userPermissions: localStorage.getItem("token") ? [] : [],
};

export const permissionSlice = createSlice({
    name: "permissions",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        addPermission: (state: IState, action: any) => {
            state.userPermissions = action.payload;
        },
    } as SliceCaseReducers<IState>,
});

export const { addPermission } = permissionSlice.actions;
export default permissionSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: **_Don't_ do this!**  You shouldn't need to do any casting at all here.

Answer (score 0):

try `as` to consider the type as `SliceCaseReducers<IState>`

```
reducers: {
    addPermission: (state: IState, action: any) => {
        state.userPermissions = action.payload;
    },
} as SliceCaseReducers<IState>,
```